# start script package.json failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i have two package.json files, one in my main directory, and one in my react-web directory...

heres the scripts:

root directory `package.json`

```
    "start": "cd react-web && npm run postinstall && export REACT_APP_CUSTOMER_ENVIRONMENT=gianlucaherokutest320880 && npm start"
```

react-web directory `package.json`

```
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=2560 checkEnvironmentForBuild && react-app-rewired start",
```

it gives me this error:

```
2021-04-20T03:29:34.532362+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the space size? try `--max-old-space-size=4096` instead of `2560`

Comment: @Tushar so i increased it, and it now brings me with this error `Error: Cannot find module '/app/react-web/react-scripts'`, although i have react-scripts installed

Comment: whats the version of your react-scripts?

Comment: @Tushar it is running version `4.0.3`

Comment: Cool so Delete node_modules and package-lock.json and run `npm install` again

Comment: @Tushar I did that, and it still brought me with the same error :(

Comment: hmm sorry the last thing I can point you to is the link. HAve alook and change the things that they say. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1363

Comment: @Tushar do I have to .gitignore node_modules folder, or no?

Comment: you should always add node_modules in .gitignore. You should not version control node_modules, because those are artifacts you can get easily with npm install or yarn install.

Comment: @Tushar okay thank you. then yea i'm not sure what the issue is unfortunately but thanks for the help

Comment: yeah keep the question open, there are a lot of smart people here, I am sure someone will come up with a solution. apologies from my side :)